# Can't Find Model after creating Folder for Controller

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel, laravel-4

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Controllers\Admin\User' not found

<?php namespace Controllers\Admin;
class UserStoreController extends BaseController{
```

Location of my Controller is app>controllers>admin>UserStoreController.php 
It would work well outside admin folder, but once it's in admin folder it would fail.

```
I also tried PSR-0 on composer.phar autoload & use app\models\user;
```

basically i'm just trying to use laravel's ORM but i cant because the controller is in the folder.

Any idea how i could go around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the autoloader

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

As JeannotLapin said, update the composer autoloader or add the path to Laravels built-in autoloading: /app/start/global.php, method ClassLoader::addDirectories()